# How can I change the syntax of showexpl's graphic key?

Tags: listings, key-value, showexpl

I'm trying to rewrite the option `graphic` from `showexpl` package, I have reviewed the source code `showexpl.sty` but, fail to find the modification, the package use `keyval` (or xkeyval) and `listings` for definition of graphic command (too confuse for me). My idea is this, the default definition is:

```
graphic={[option]path/to/image}
```

and I want to change it to:

```
graphic={option}{path/to/image}
```

Is it possible to change this?

Saludos,

Pablo

**EDIT:** These are the lines from latest `showexpl.sty` I have tried to modify:

```
% lines 66 - 72
\newcommand*\SX@graphicname{}%
\newcommand*\SX@graphicparam{}%
\lst@Key{graphic}{}[]{%
  \lstKV@OptArg[width=\linewidth]{#1}{%
    \edef\SX@graphicparam{##1}\edef\SX@graphicname{##2}%
  }%
}%
```

I tried to modify @ Key ... did not work

```
% lines 170 - 189
\lstnewenvironment{LTXexample}[1][]
{%
  \@temptokena{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \advance\c@ltxexample\@ne \advance\c@lstlisting\@ne
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset,#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\SX@codefile{\SX@codefile}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicname{\SX@graphicname}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicparam{\SX@graphicparam}}%
  \x
  \xdef\SX@@explpreset{\the\@temptokena,codefile=\SX@codefile,
    graphic={[\SX@graphicparam]{\SX@graphicname}}}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup% Warum noetig?
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\SX@codefile}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile\egroup
  \SX@put@code@result
}
```

change the line `graphic={\SX@graphicparam}{\SX@graphicname}}` does not work ...
And MWE (for aclaration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[graphic={[width=5cm]demo}]
change 
graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to 
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide an MWE of your trials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is possible (see below), I'm not sure why you would want to change the syntax of the `graphic` key... With the syntax you suggest, what used to be an optional argument will become mandatory. Are you sure that's really what you want?

---

First, to make the `graphic` key accept its arguments as

```
graphic={option}{path/to/image}
```

instead of

```
graphic={[option]path/to/image}
```

you need to redefine that key using the `listings` internal macro called `\lstKV@TwoArg` instead of `\lstKV@OptArg`:

```
\lst@Key{graphic}{}[]{%
  \lstKV@TwoArg{#1}{%
    \edef\SX@graphicparam{##1}\edef\SX@graphicname{##2}%
  }%
}%
```

Then, because the old syntax of the `graphic` key is used in the definition of the `LTXexample` environment, you must redefine the latter to work with the new syntax instead.

1. The `listings` package does not provide any macro to redefine an environment; therefore, you must undefine the `LTXexample` environment "manually":

   ```
   \let\LTXexample\undefined
   \let\LTXexample@\undefined
   ```
2. You can now redefine the latter to work with your new syntax for the `graphic` key:

   ```
   ...
   \xdef\SX@@explpreset{\the\@temptokena,codefile=\SX@codefile,
     graphic={\SX@graphicparam}{\SX@graphicname}}%
   ...
   ```

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\makeatletter

% redefinition of showexpl's graphic key
% so that the syntax be {...}{...} instead of {[...]{...}}
\lst@Key{graphic}{}[]{%
  \lstKV@TwoArg{#1}{%
    \edef\SX@graphicparam{##1}\edef\SX@graphicname{##2}%
  }%
}%

% `undefinition' of LTXexample environment
\let\LTXexample\undefined
\let\LTXexample@\undefined

% redefinition of the LTXexample environment
% with the new syntax of the graphic key
\lstnewenvironment{LTXexample}[1][]
{%
  \@temptokena{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \advance\c@ltxexample\@ne \advance\c@lstlisting\@ne
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset,#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\SX@codefile{\SX@codefile}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicname{\SX@graphicname}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicparam{\SX@graphicparam}}%
  \x
  \xdef\SX@@explpreset{\the\@temptokena,codefile=\SX@codefile,
    graphic={\SX@graphicparam}{\SX@graphicname}}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup%
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\SX@codefile}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile\egroup
  \SX@put@code@result
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[graphic={width=5cm}{demo}]
change 
graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to 
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit (following OP's comment)

You can, if you want, define a new environment based on `LTXexample` but using the custom syntax of your `graphic` key. However, you'll run in trouble if you try to use both that new environment and `LTXexample` because the latter still relies on the old `graphic` syntax. One way around is to define a new key (called `mygraphic` below) instead of redefining the `graphic` key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\makeatletter


% definition of a new key based on showexpl's graphic key
% but those syntax is {...}{...} instead of {[...]{...}}
\lst@Key{mygraphic}{}[]{%
  \lstKV@TwoArg{#1}{%
    \edef\SX@graphicparam{##1}\edef\SX@graphicname{##2}%
  }%
}%

% definition of a new environment based on LTXexample
% but using the new syntax of the graphic key
\lstnewenvironment{MYexample}[1][]
{%
  \@temptokena{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \advance\c@ltxexample\@ne \advance\c@lstlisting\@ne
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset,#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\SX@codefile{\SX@codefile}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicname{\SX@graphicname}%
      \def\noexpand\SX@graphicparam{\SX@graphicparam}}%
  \x
  \xdef\SX@@explpreset{\the\@temptokena,codefile=\SX@codefile,
    mygraphic={\SX@graphicparam}{\SX@graphicname}}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup%
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\SX@codefile}%
}
{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile\egroup
  \SX@put@code@result
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{MYexample}[mygraphic={width=5cm}{demo}]
change 
graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to 
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{MYexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[pos=r]
change graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I need change the syntax of the graphic key for compatibility whit tcblisting in one package for examples (and future regex in script perl). Saludos

Comment: If try to change LTXexample for MYexample not found...??

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL See my edit.

Comment: OK, but does cause interference with "LTXexample" show error `]`, i need the modification only for MYexample.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL What do you mean?

Comment: try this \begin{MYexample}[graphic={width=5cm}{demo}]
change 
graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to 
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{MYexample}


\begin{LTXexample}[pos=r]
change 
graphic={[width=5cm]demo}
to 
graphic={width=5cm}{demo}
\end{LTXexample}

Comment: You get an error because `LTXexample` still relies on the old definition of the `graphic` key. The easiest way out is to choose a different name for your custom `graphic` key. See my edit.